# Symfony2: doctrine:mapping:import throws Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException - Table [...] has no primary key.

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to import a Doctrine mapping for a table called stores. I do:

```
./app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyBundle annotation --filter="stores"
```

I get the error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                              
  Table Cat_map has no primary key. Doctrine does not support reverse engineering from tables that don't have a prima  
  ry key.
```

Am I using the filter incorrectly? I dont want doctrine to try and map any table other than 'stores'

Requested create syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `stores` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `storeid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=96 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: you should include in your question the SQL code that describes the tables you're trying to import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the *--filter* attribute Doctrine analyse all the tables.
If everything is OK then it go through the filter creating only the specified entity.

So, you should try to fix the **cat_map** table adding a primary key.
If you're not figuring out a way or if you got particular needs, please update your question including the **cat_map** part.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This helped me, thanks!! Who would have thought that --filter does not actually filter?

Comment: Hopefully this pull request will fix this issue with filter : https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/473

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Doctrine to ignore tables that match a certain regex. For example, if you want to ignore tables that begin with "custom_", put this in your config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: /^(?!custom_)/
```

This seems to do the trick. For for information: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#manual-tables

Answer (score 0):

Use something other than doctrine for existing databases. Doctrine hasn't fixed this issue for many years.