# Generate single Symfony2 entity from an existing table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I need the command to generate a single entity from an existing database and I cannot get the command formatted correctly. I changed my setup to the DB in parameters.yml to look at the database in question and then I run:
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle xml --filter="tbl_remote"

This keeps on complaining that some table that is not related to tbl_remote does not have a primary key. From the error message I can see that it is looking at the correct database but I need to create and entity for only one table.

From my understanding this will create an xml file and to get the entity I will run:
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:tbl_remote --path src/

Why will it not create the xml file?

Comment: I saw : "Despite the --filter attribute Doctrine analyse all the tables." in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221967/symfony2-doctrinemappingimport-throws-doctrine-orm-mapping-mappingexception article ... that sucks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After finding that the `--filter` does not do what I hoped, I scripted `tbl_remote` and created it in my test database. I then changed `parameters.yml` to look at the test database and after running:  `php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --filter="tbl_remote" AppBundle` 
i was greeted with: "Database does not have any mapping information."

This is not my day so I just ran: `php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle` and removed the .orm.xml that I did not need.

I was then able to run: `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle`
 to generate the single entity!! Not what I wanted but not a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

to generate a single entity from the database I use this little `sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear;
echo "####################################################################################################"
echo "# Generating the Doctrine files for a given entity, be carefull that the entities are CamelCased". #"
echo "####################################################################################################"
date

# Testing arguments
EXPECTED_ARGS=1
E_BADARGS=65
if [ $# -ne $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
  echo "Usage: ./`basename $0` MyEntity"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi

php app/console doctrine:mapping:import CoreBundle annotation --filter=$1
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Project\\Bundle\\CoreBundle\\Entity\\$1
echo "  --> Done!"
date
```